# Can't get Region Monitoring to function

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, core-location

After trying for a while using [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html), Stackoverflow, Google, I still can't get a simple UIAlertView to show up when I enter or exit a region I am monitoring.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

for (CLRegion *monitored in [self.locationManager monitoredRegions])
    [locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:monitored];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.latitude = 31.521603;
coord.longitude = 33.01190;
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc]initWithCenter:coord radius:20 identifier:@"work"];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self showMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EnterRegion: %@",region.identifier] andMessage:@"Welcome Home" andButton:@"Ok"];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self showMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ExitRegion: %@",region.identifier] andMessage:@"Bye Bye" andButton:@"Ok"];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Now monitoring for %@", region.identifier);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error{
    [self showMessage:@"msg" andMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Region Failed:%@",region.identifier] andButton:@"ok"];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self showMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did Determine State: %@. state:%@",region.identifier, (state == CLRegionStateUnknown) ? @"Unknown" : (state == CLRegionStateInside) ? @"INSIDE" : @"OUTSIDE"] andMessage:@"Determined" andButton:@"Ok"];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{ }
```

`showMessage` is just a UIAlertView popping to the user.
sometimes I get `monitoringDidFailForRegion` when I set up the region sometimes I don't.
I was thinking if I should mark my app as using "Background Modes" for Location Updates, but this has not changed a thing. Seems like it should work, but I can never get didEnterRegion nor didExitRegion to be called.

I should point out that I updated the `info.plist` with the required keys:

```
 <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Location is required for geofence</string>
```

`Background app refresh` is set to `On`, locations enabled. Testing outside, physically, I can't get the functions to be called.
What is it that can be wrong here? is 20 meters too short to define a region? 
Could it be that region monitoring is not working for an app that is on the foreground? silencing the callbacks?

Comment: The minimum size of a region should be  100m. Are you already inside the region when you start the app?

Comment: Yes, I am inside the region, when I exit and return, no callback gets called, even on apples sample code. I just came back from a 200 meter radius region trip

Comment: After adding the region to be monitored I suggest that you wait a second or so and then call `requestStateForRegion`. Also implement the delegate method `didDetermineState:forRegion:`. I have some sample code https://bitbucket.org/paulw11/locationtest

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I just checked the code for the default of 1000.0m, and it worked... I could get Apple's sample code to function for 1000m, but when I changed the code for the Annotation and the region, to be 100m, it stops working. Just came in from a trip with the car

Comment: Is your device is iPhone with GPS?

Comment: Yes, iPhone 6plus. Is it possible my accuracy is not high enough for some reason? Is 20meters even possible for region monitoring?

Comment: It should be fine, depending on the area (tall buildings can be a problem).  I believe that if you specify a region smaller than 100m radius, iOS increases the radius to 100m